Azure DevOps Pipeline: Building and Testing Separate .NET Projects in Same Solution
In azure DevOps I have an organisation with 2 .NET projects: "MyProject" and "MyProject.Tests". Both projects belong to the same solution. I am building a pipepeline, and the YAML file is located in "MyProject".
The below code snippet from this YAML file is supposed to build "MyProject" and then run tests from "MyProject.Tests"
jobs:
- job: Build and Test
  displayName: Build and Test
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/MyProject.csproj'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '**/MyProject.Tests.csproj'

The build task (DotNetCoreCLI@2 with build command) works fine for "MyProject.csproj", but the test task (DotNetCoreCLI@2 with test command) fails to find "MyProject.Tests.csproj" (I know that '**/MyProject.Tests.csproj' is an incorrect path). How can I modify my YAML file to correctly reference and run the unit tests from "MyProject.Tests.csproj" after building "MyProject.csproj"?
Additional Details:

Both projects (MyProject and MyProject.Tests) are part of the same solution.
I'm using NUnit for unit testing in MyProject.Tests.
The pipeline YAML file is located in the root directory of MyProject.
The goal is to build MyProject first and then run unit tests from MyProject.Tests using Azure DevOps pipeline.
Any insights or corrections on how to structure the YAML file or reference the test project correctly would be greatly appreciated!

"MyProject" file structure
MyProject.Tests" file structure

Why don't you put the yaml file out side of both project, next to the .sln file. Then, you don't even need to provide the project directive or simply a wide card **/*.csproj for both cases

@quyentho, thank you for your advice.
the .sln and YAML files are placed on the same level in the MyProject project. there is  a path in there to the test project that looks like this: ..\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj but it does not really work. any suggestions?

Did you try to remove the project directive? because the  dotnet test command will use the csproj/sln  to find the csproject needed to run build and tests

@StanSm789 You can try to loop over the files in the source directory and check if the test file can be found. Refer to the answer below. If it still not work, you can share the screenshot about the project files structure(test project and my project) and you can share more error message with us. It will be helpful to investigate the issue furhter.

@quyentho, although dotnet test command works locally, when running the pipeline  without project directive I have the following error:
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[warning]No test result files were found.

@StanSm789 The project directive is required when using dotnet test task. Or it will not find the correct test project file to run the test. You need to make sure that the MyProject.Tests.csproj  can be found by dotnet test task.

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, all project files will be checked out to the source folder: $(Build.sourcesdirectory) by default.
To make sure that the MyProject.Tests.csproj can be found correctly, you can set the following path to the dotnet test task. projects: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/**/MyProject.Tests.csproj'
For example:
jobs:
- job: Build and Test
  displayName: Build and Test
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/MyProject.csproj'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/**/MyProject.Tests.csproj'

It will go through all the files in the source folder to find matching files.
Update:
From your screenshots about the project files structure, the MyProject and MyProject.tests are from two repos.
To use the files in the Pipeline, you need to add the repo resources in Azure Pipeline.
Then you need to checkout two repos in Azure Pipeline. Then you will find the related csproj files.
For example:
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyProjectTests 
    type: git
    name: YourProjectName/MyProject.Tests 



jobs:
- job: Build and Test
  displayName: Build and Test
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: MyProjectTests
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/**/MyProject.csproj'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/**/MyProject.Tests.csproj'


Thank you for your advice!
I added
projects: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/**/MyProject.Tests.csproj'
Despite the pipeline output indicating successful completion, upon reviewing the task output, I encountered the following warning message:
##[warning]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

To provide more context, the structure of MyProject at the root level includes typical MVC folders along with MyProject.sln, MyProject.csproj, appsettings.json, and related files.
Within MyProject.Tests, you'll find folders containing unit tests such as Controllers, Models, and the MyProject.Tests.cs file.
Please advise on any further steps to correctly configure the pipeline to identify and execute the unit tests located within MyProject.Tests.

@StanSm789 Do you mean that the MyProject.Tests folder doesnot have csproj file?

Can you run the project successfully on your local machine?

MyProject.Tests does have .csproj file. Also, I can run the project successfully on the local machine by usingCtrl + R - T or pressing Run All Tests button

@StanSm789 If possible, can you edit your question to share the screenshot of the whole project files structure. I can't clearly understand the specific location just by describing it.

done, I have added the screenshots to my question

@StanSm789 From you screenshot, the two projects are from two repos. You need to use repo resources in Azure Pipeline to checkout two repos. Then you can define the file path. Please refer to the update in my answer above for more details.
